# Does "manage-members" permission in fine grain permission in Keycloak does allow to create new user?

Tags: permissions, keycloak, roles

I have a similar problem of the issue [Create-user-only Keycloak role?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53599871/3611149) and [KeyCloak restricting user management to certain groups while enabling 'manage-users'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51616770/3611149) but on a different Keycloak version : I have an admin group and a final user group. I want admin to manage only admin users and not to be able to see or add user into the final user group.

I achieve, with a admin user, to see only users of the "admin" group, but he can't add new user. I'm doing this by enable the fine grain permission.

The "manage-members" permission on "admin" group is activated but it seems that it doesn't allow to create new user into the realm group.

If I allow "manage-user" of "realm-management" client, my admin user will be able to create new user but he will see again all final users...

I'm using Keycloak 7.0.1. Is there now a way of doing this ?